# Bulk import in NEO4j

Tags: neo4j, bulkinsert, bulk-load

Data (snippet) in  node file:

```
C0243192
C1522005
C1524024
C1524059
C1623416
C1959616.......
```

Header file for Node file:

```
conceptID:ID
```

Relationship(snippet) file date:

```
C0000039,C0001555,AQ_
C0000039,C0001688,AQ_
C0000039,C0002776,AQ_ .....
```

Header file for relationship file:

```
:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE
```

When I try to run bulk import script as

```
neo4j-import --into graph.db --nodes:concept "MRREl-nodes,nheader" --relationships "MRREl-relations,rheader" --deliminiter ,  --skip-duplicate-node true
```

I get error:

```
 Error in input data
 Caused by:Missing header of type START_ID, among entries [C0000005:string, C0036775:string, RB_:string]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was there because I was putting the header file after the data file

Instead of

```
MRREl-nodes,nheader
```

it should be

```
nheader,MRREl-nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the `delimiter` keyword:

```
neo4j-import --into graph.db --nodes:concept "MRREl-nodes,nheader" --relationships "MRREl-relations,rheader" --delimiter ","  --skip-duplicate-node true
```

where (apart of a typo) you should quote your separator, in this case `","`, or even avoid it since the comma is the default.

Hope that helps.